# How to post an app on google play over he 150mb limit?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I'm try to upload a app on the google play store but its around 250mb, and when i upload the .aab on google play i get "One or more of the auto-generated multi-APKs exceeds the maximum allowed size of 150 MB."

ive been searching and search on how to bypass this, ive tried removing some files from the app to make it smaller but its not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to go is:

1. with play asset delivery
   https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery

Or

2. play feature delivery (dynamic feature)
   https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery

Comment: is this able to work with .aab?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. OBBs are incompatible with AABs. Use dynamic delivery: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery

Comment: @Pierre good catch... I had missed that change. I corrected the answer!